# How to create a drop down with custom json data format in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my custom json data

```
 {0: {'Married Status': {'M', '', 'S'}}, 1: {'COMNCTN_IND': {'', 'OFC', 'RES', 'PGR'}}}
```

I  have tried this,

**Code:**

```
   <select ng-model="ddldates" ng-options="number.dates for number in dates">
        </select>

    </div>
</body>

<script>
    angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller('myController', function ($scope, $filter) {




     $scope.dates=[{0: {'Married Status': {'M', '', 'S'}}, 1: {'COMNCTN_IND': {'', 'OFC', 'RES', 'PGR'}}}];

        });



</script>
```

How to add drop down? Please help.
I want to what should I write in ng option for my data

Comment: How should the dropdown look like?

Comment: This isn't a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <select ng-model="ddldates">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.married_status">{{item.status}}</option>
   </select>

   <select ng-model="ddldates2">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.COMNCTN_IND">{{item.comm_ind}}</option>
   </select>





</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.dates={};
$scope.dates.married_status =[{status:"M"}, {status:""}, {status:"S"}];
$scope.dates.COMNCTN_IND       =[{comm_ind:""}, {comm_ind:"OFC"}, {comm_ind:"RES"}, {comm_ind:"PGR"}];

    console.log($scope.dates);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

not sure what you are trying to do.
try this.

TLDR:

```
$scope.dates={};
$scope.dates.married_status=[{status:"M"}, {status:""}, {status:"S"}];
$scope.dates.COMNCTN_IND=[{comm_ind:""}, {comm_ind:"OFC"}, {comm_ind:"RES"}, {comm_ind:"PGR"}];



   <select ng-model="ddldates">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.married_status">{{item.status}}</option>
   </select>

   <select ng-model="ddldates2">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.COMNCTN_IND">{{item.comm_ind}}</option>
   </select>
```

Full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <select ng-model="ddldates">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.married_status">{{item.status}}</option>
   </select>

   <select ng-model="ddldates2">
    <option ng-repeat="item in dates.COMNCTN_IND">{{item.comm_ind}}</option>
   </select>





</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.dates={};
$scope.dates.married_status =[{status:"M"}, {status:""}, {status:"S"}];
$scope.dates.COMNCTN_IND        =[{comm_ind:""}, {comm_ind:"OFC"}, {comm_ind:"RES"}, {comm_ind:"PGR"}];

    console.log($scope.dates);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to covert `{'Married Status': {'M', '', 'S'}}` to `{status:"M"}, {status:""}, {status:"S"}`?

Comment: make it an array

Comment: object keys cant have spaces in them. 2: make it an array
im not sure i understand your question or what you want to do